# Webcam Torch UWP without GUI

Tags: user-interface, uwp, webcam, flashlight

we wrote a program for our technicians to make pictures from defect machinery with their Ultrabooks webcams. We used AForge for this.
But now the Ultrabooks have flashlights and the users want to use them to make better pictures.
I tried this with AForge but was not able to activate the flashlight. (Tried for months). Now I tried with UWP and got this to work in couple of minutes.
But with UWP there comes the GUI.
Is there any way to run an UWP program without the GUI? I searched for this, and everything I found says no. But maybe just to "open the GUI and take the picture and close it immediately"? Or any other idea how to do this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How do you take a picture without a viewfinder?

Comment: Don't know what you mean. The Webcam takes a picture of what is in front of it.

Comment: You mean you have one app taking the picture and a different app turning on the torch? Can you add the torch code to the app taking the picture?

Comment: No, maybe i have not explained it to well. I now have this UWP app to make a picture with activated flashlight. But this has the GUI. I have no idea how to run UWP without GUI.

Comment: What is "Aforge"? Is that a program you wrote? Do you need a UWP if this is for desktop Windows?